# `baseline` option for date values does not work in Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a baseline on a chart that uses date values to chart. Here is the code, and here is what the chart looks like:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Assignment');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Dummy');
  data.addRows([
    ['A', new Date(2011,1,1)],
    ['B', new Date(2012,1,1)], 
    ['C', new Date(2013,1,1)],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {
             width:600, height:400,
             hAxis: {baseline: new Date(2012,6,1), baselineColor: 'red'}
           }
      );
}
```

[image: Baseline on Left]

This is not the expected behavior -- the baseline is set to be on July 1st, 2012, yet it is appearing all the way to the left (January 1st, 2011).

If you do this with a non-date Axis chart, the behavior is different:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Assignment');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dummy');
  data.addRows([
    ['A', 1],
    ['B', 2], 
    ['C', 3],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {
             width:600, height:400,
             hAxis: {baseline: 1.5, baselineColor: 'red'}
           }
      );
}
```

[image: correct baseline sample]

What the heck is going on here? Is it impossible to set the baseline of a date-axis chart?

Comment: The "baseline" option seems to be ignored for dates in the current release version.  I suspect (though cannot confirm) that this will be fixed when the dev team fixes the other problems with date axes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Some quirks are good (just look at Excel, it is all quirks!), but some of the behavior on these is bad quirky. I guess it's time to wait for a fix.

Comment: @jmac did you fix this problem?

Comment: @EkaitzHernandezTroyas I haven't tried since to be honest. Why not try the same code and see how it shows up if you use the latest library? Probably the quickest way to check.