# Plotting a timeline with different colors in the same line with Python (Gantt-Chart?)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I have a question concerning a plot I'd like to make. I have data of leaders (dictators, presidents, chancellors...) from all over the world and the date when they got to power and when they lost it. Additionally I have information if the regime was a dictatorship, democracy or something else...

My plan is to have a plot with all countries in the data and different bars for their leaders. Depending on the regime category I'd like to have different colors. I have 6 different regime categories.

I tried to find something, found plot.ly but no luck with that.

A small text example, I hope you can imagine what I'm planning to do (not reperesentative!).

```
"-" = democracy
"~" = monarchy
"x" = dictatorship

USA:            ----|---------|----------|------|--------|-----------|-----

UK:             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~|-------|---|-----|-----

GER:            --------|xxxxxxxxxx|---------|---------|--------|
```

My data starts in 1945, but not all countries have existed by then, so some bars will start in 1970.
I'd say it's like a stacked horizontal gantt-chart. But after trying with plotly without a result I'm curious for other solutions.

**Thanks for your help!**

edit: Maybe I should add: I imported the data as pd.DataFrame and tried that for plot.ly as well.

edit 2:
I managed to get a result, it's a bit ugly, the text on the left is not fully visible, the "legend" hides behind a scroll bar and has no names, just the keys assigned in the data. I tried to use a dict for the layout, didn't work. I saw that in the documentation, but it doesn't work, what do I do wrong, would be nicer for adaption.
The current version: https://plot.ly/~derhannes/10.embed

```
# The actual plotting
fig = ff.create_gantt(df_dd_gantt_final, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=False, height=2400, width=1200, title='Regimes in history worldwide', showgrid_x=True, group_tasks=True)
py.iplot(fig, filename='regimes', world_readable=True)
```

Comment: Something like this, with more colors and more lines...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219413/creating-a-timeline-with-a-bar-chart-in-google-charts

Comment: If you're plotting data in Python (and aren't concerned with the interactivity of plotly), the main library people tend to use is [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) often with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) on top. As it stands, you could do with editing your question to add in some examples of what you've tried, and some sample data for people to look at.

Comment: The interactivity is actually only a side effect, but plotly seems nicer, somehow I didn't find too much about Gantt Charts with matplotlib or they looked super ugly. [I got some results with plotly and try to adapt the layout now.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524712/edit-layout-of-plotly-gantt-chart-with-dataframe-and-timedelta)